# Can't get data from vector inside another vector

Tags: c++, sdl

Let me explain the situation:

I have a class cAnimation with few methods

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class cAnimation{

    private:
      vector<SDL_Rect> frames;

    public:
       cAnimation();
       void setQntFrames(int n){
           this->frames.resize(n);
           ofstream log("qntframes.txt");
           log << "capacity = " << this->frames.capacity();
       }

       void setFrame(int index,int x, int y, int w, int h){
           this->frames[index].x = x;
           this->frames[index].y = y;
           this->frames[index].w = w;
           this->frames[index].h = h; 

           ofstream log("setrect.txt");
           log << "i = " << i
               << "x = " << this->frames.at(i).x
               << "y = " << this->frames.at(i).y
               << "w = " << this->frames.at(i).w
               << "h = " << this->frames.at(i).h;
       }

       SDL_Rect cAnimation::getFrame(int index){
           return this->frames[index];
       }
};
```

I'm doing this at my main.cpp (the includes are all ok)

```
vector<cAnimation> animation;

animation.resize(1);
animation[0].setQntFrames(10);          // it's printing the right value on qntframes.txt
animation[0].setFrame(0,10,10,200,200)  // it's printing the right values on setrect.txt

SDL_Rect temp = animation[0].getFrame(0);// here is the problem

ofstream log("square.txt");
log << "x = " << temp.x
    << "y = " << temp.y;
```

when i look to the square.txt log, some weird chars like squares appears and when i try to use de data of SDL_Rect temp, the application just terminate, what i'm doing wrong here to get the values?

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org to see how and why you should reduce your code to a trivial test case.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably outputting chars. When you output these to an ostream, you'll get the ASCII character, instead of the numeric value of the ASCII character. Try this:

```
log << "x = " << (int) temp.x
    << "y = " << (int) temp.y;
```

A 'char' is frequently used as short hand for a 1-byte integer. They work well for this, except that when you output them to a stream, it attempts to output them as an ASCII character, instead of as a one-byte integer. Casting the character to a true integer usually fixes the problem.

Comment: still saving the same weird characters on the file, this can be some wrong memory access?

Comment: SDL_Rect components are not type char.  They are Sint16, which is just a typedef for `short` on most systems.

Comment: I'm saving the data using the same "mode" on the method, just there temp where i get data from the vector frames isn't saving cool, and the termination is terminating at the same instant when i try to use temp to do something.

Comment: Ah, rats, bad guess then. It might be helpful to know what square.txt actually contains -- it does sound like it's ASCII junk. Given that the program crashes when you use 'temp', you probably do have some type of memory access problem.

Comment: Can i repair this or use another data structure to store the data? (sry about my english)

Comment: http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL-1.3-docs/SDL__stdinc_8h.html#771540b301912156f79ee72e9a168178: "typedef int16_t  Sint16  A signed 16-bit integer type."